# Test to compare different subgroups when using same control

Tags: hypothesis-testing, control-group

I am interested in finding out if the effect sizes between subgroups are significant are not. Here's the scenario:

I have performed Analysis 1: Controls vs. Disease

Now, Disease is subdivided into DisA, DisB, DisC. And I have tested

Analysis 2a: Controls vs. DisA, 
Analysis 2b: Controls vs. DisB, and 
Analysis 2c: Controls vs. DisC.

I am looking into tests where I can compare the effect sizes for Analysis 1 vs. Analysis 2a, Analysis 1 vs. Analysis 2b etc.

and also (secondarily) compare between Analysis 2* models.

I am not sure what test to use since the "Controls" group is the same across each of the analyses.